# How to integrate Odoo Database with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, odoo, odoo-11

I am working a project where entire application is developed using Laravel 5.5 (postgres). Now, our client came up with a requirement for having ERP and they opted to use ODOO 11 with very minimal customizations.

So , my concern is with database schema of odoo (like res.users conflicts with users table of laravel) and other basic integrations as such.

Being new to ODOO I don't know how much is the possibility of Laravel-Odoo integration.

I want to know is there any possible ways to integrate laravel and odoo database as one and do customization ?? And is there anyone out there who tried this already can help me with this ????

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://github.com/Edujugon/laradoo

Comment: @J.Doe this is only for providing API right ?? What I need is to merge databases of laravel and odoo as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odoo supports XML-RPC and JSON-RPC. Odoo is usually extended internally via modules, but many of its features and all of its data are also available from the outside for external analysis or integration with various tools. Part of the Model Reference API is easily available over XML-RPC and accessible from a variety of languages.

Please have a look here https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/webservices/odoo.html you'll get the sample code how to interact with Odoo objects.

Hope this helps.

--
Regards
VK